# thought were the same combinatorial

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, combinations

I was under the impression that $${52\choose 5!5!5!5!5!} = {52\choose 5}{47\choose 5}{42\choose 5}{37\choose 5}{32\choose 5} $$

Reason i ask is because i was trying to solve a simple number of ways to deal 52 cards in hands of 5 cards amongst 5 players. I tried it both ways and got different solutions, but when looking at the proof it says they are equivalent, or is that only if you go all the way to 0?

Comment: ${52\choose 5!5!5!5!5!}$ is not a valid expression, since $52<5!5!5!5!5!$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you mean is $\displaystyle {52 \choose 5,5,5,5,5,27} = 
\dfrac{52!}{5!\; 5!\; 5!\; 5!\; 5!\; 27!}$.

Comment: you're right, and on top of that if I am going to express it in that expanded "choose" form I better make note to include the 27. Thanks